# Cache not used with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, ehcache, spring-cache

In a spring boot application who have a rest implementation (no session with spring security), i would like to avoid multiple call to database for user table.

In a class who extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, i have

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProviderBean() throws Excen {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    authenticationProvider.setUserCache(userCache);
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsServiceBean());

    return authenticationProvider;
}

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

    @Bean
    public EhCacheFactoryBean ehCacheFactoryBean(){
        EhCacheFactoryBean ehCacheFactory = new EhCacheFactoryBean();
        ehCacheFactory.setCacheManager(cacheManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
        return ehCacheFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(){
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(cacheManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cacheManagerFactoryBean() {
        EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cacheManager = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        return cacheManager;
    }


    @Bean
    public UserCache userCache() {
        EhCacheBasedUserCache userCache = new EhCacheBasedUserCache();
        userCache.setCache(ehCacheFactoryBean().getObject());
        return userCache;
    }
}
```

ehcache.xml (possibility to do it in java?)

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true" monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true"> 
  <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/> 
  <defaultCache 
     maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000" 
     eternal="false" 
     timeToIdleSeconds="60" 
     timeToLiveSeconds="300" 
     maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000000" 
     diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120" 
     memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"> 
     <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/> 
  </defaultCache> 
</ehcache>
```

How to be sure then my cache is used?

actually i see query done on the server

Comment: All that code can go away with Spring Boot. We automatically detect `ehcache.xml` and we configure it for you. You only need the `@EnableCaching` one to trigger it. If you have the actuator, we export stats for each cache on `/metrics`.

Comment: ok and how to said use my cache when user try to log?

Comment: Oh I get the problem now. You're trying to enable the second level cache of Hibernate I guess. You should head over the hibernate documentation or rephrase your question because that's not going to do that at all. What you're configuring Spring's cache abstraction, [check the doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to enable statistics. By adding `statistics="true"` if I recall correctly. So you will see cache hit and miss in JMX by registering the cache manager.

```
MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
ManagementService.registerMBeans(cacheManager, mBeanServer, false, false, false, true);
```

In your code, that would mean

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager(){
    net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager cacheManager = cacheManagerFactoryBean().getObject();

    MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    ManagementService.registerMBeans(cacheManager, mBeanServer, false, false, false, true);

    return new EhCacheCacheManager(cacheManager);
}
```

Setting logs to DEBUG for `net.sf.ehcache.Cache` will also give you some info like cache creations, expirations and so on. However, you won't see hit and miss.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a demo code:

```
@Cacheable(value = "v")
public Object get(int id){
    System.out.println("get from db");
    return dao.findById(id);
}
```

If your cache is work, there is no any output in your console.